# How best to implement function pointers in a C++ dialect that does not support it?

Tags: c++

For example, OpenCL doesn't support function pointers. Nor do some toolchains targeting embedded hardware. RPC needs an equivalent to a function pointer that works across disjoint heaps. So hopefully there's enough prior art for this to have a known (though not yet to me) good solution.

I've tagged this question 'C++', even though I am aware that a language which looks like C++ but doesn't have function pointers is in fact not C++. It's still the closest fit. I have templates and so forth available, just not much runtime support.

For example, one could require the programmer to assign an enum to every function they would like to pass around by pointer and write a switch that issues a direct call to each function. Plus pass around elements of that enum, instead of the address of the function, and do something with unions to handle variation in arguments.

Or, one could hash the symbol name of the function (semi-automatically assigning the value) and write a switch based on those hashes. That's what I'm doing today, but with custom compiler support that I'd like to eliminate.

Writing out either switch by hand, adding an entry when required, isn't great. Perhaps therefore one can build an if/else chain by unrolling a loop over a global array.

There's no type safety here, so perhaps it should be separate hash / enum / array / other per function type. That would remove some unions.

After a couple of months thinking about it off and on I haven't seen a clean / maintainable solution (which isn't a bespoke compiler pass). Thoughts welcome.

Comment: I'm confused. If you don't have a function pointer but you have an API that needs a function pointer (so it's obviously going to call the FP) how do you implement an alternative ? - it's not your code that needs to do something, it is the other API that you don't control. Or are you asking how you would write an version of the other API that doesn't use FPs ? (still cant call the real other lib because it needs FPs and you don't have 'em)

Comment: Does your platform support objects with virtual member functions?

Comment: "Writing out either switch by hand, adding an entry when required, isn't great." That's what scripts are for. In one of my project I used a single XML definition to autogenerate POD declarations, then robo-generate C++ code to serialize it. Something along those lines. Don't write the switch by hand, have a script write it for you. Although C++ can cure the common cold, it can't solve all the world's problems, and sometimes you need to go beyond C++ and use other tools to solve the pressing problem of the day.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track for using switches.

Back in 1999 - 2001 I was the main dev on a project which has since [nearly vanished from the web](https://www.digitalbroadcasting.com/doc/opticboom-plug-in-0001), doing realtime stereoscopic 3D rendering inside Apple's Quicktime.

It provided a custom movie format that took a standard 2D video, combined it with a 256 level *depth track* and rendered each frame.

The playback offered a choice of output:

- different kinds of coloured lens glasses: cyan-red, red-green etc., as often in novelties, where 3D is achieved by a masking offset
- different colored lens glasses in monochrome, where color was only used to provide the depth effect - very useful for fine detailed scientific and mining data, like looking at rocks
- synchronised shutter LCD glasses, which ran at 60Hz plugged inline to a 120Hz CRT, and
- very early glasses-free display (about $100K each, used at conferences).

This ran on Windows and classic Mac devices of that era doing realtime rendering at 24fps. Not easy on hardware such as a G3 [iMac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMac_G3) 350MHz PowerPC.

It also had the ability to adjust depth rendering effects per-frame. You could choose to have a movie appear *in front* or *behind* the screen and adjust the *depth amplitude* for how far away things seem.

So, coupled with different movie formats there was a **lot** of stuff to switch on which could vary continuously.

I regard this as the pinnacle of my programming career. It was a fun and immensely challenging project working out **how** to provide this 3D rendering inside Quicktime, as well as technically challenging getting the performance. At the WWDC in 2000, Apple QuickTime engineers were congratulatory and stunned we'd done it. It was all done using standard QuickTime APIs and ran extremely robustly, no hacks involved.

The big code example below shows how I used templates and switches. The nested switch statements broke down the per-frame variables discussed above.

The nested switches are run once per frame being rendered. They result in a unique function being invoked which loops each pixel being rendered - I think roughly 700 different variations are generated by the templates.

I remember a major upgrade to CodeWarrior compiler came out partway through the project which optimised templated functions. Our compile time went up by a factor of 4 but the resulting code was a lot smaller and faster.

```cpp
// from rendererersP.h

/**
this template definition provides the implementation of the
stereo pair algorithm for the argument class types.

pass a single StereoRenderPars struct which tells the function
about the source and destination data.
*/
template<class ImageFormat, 
         class DepthFormat, 
         class GlassFormat, 
         class DestinationFormat>
void RenderStereoPair (StereoRenderPars *rp)
{


// from render_switch.cpp
// the entry point for stereo
int
renderStereo(GlassType gt, ImageFormat sf, StereoRenderPars *rp, bool outputGrey)
{
  int status = 0;

  switch (gt)    // The GT Stringers!
  {
    case gtRLeftBGRight :
      {
        switch (outputGrey)
        {
          case true :
            {
              switch (sf)
              {
                case ifRGB :
                  RenderStereoPair<ImageGrayRGB, DepthUnsigned24, GlassRLeftBGRight, ImageGrayRGB>(rp);
                  break;
                case ifBGR :
                  RenderStereoPair<ImageGrayBGR, DepthUnsigned24, GlassRLeftBGRight, ImageGrayBGR>(rp);
                  break;
                case ifARGB :
                  RenderStereoPair<ImageGrayARGB, DepthUnsigned32, GlassRLeftBGRight, ImageGrayARGB>(rp);
                  break;
                case ifBGRA :
                  RenderStereoPair<ImageGrayBGRA, DepthUnsigned32, GlassRLeftBGRight, ImageGrayBGRA>(rp);
                  break;
                case if555RGB :
                  RenderStereoPair<ImageGray555RGB, DepthUnsigned16, GlassRLeftBGRight, ImageGray555RGB>(rp);
                  break;
                case if565RGB :
                  RenderStereoPair<ImageGray565RGB, DepthUnsigned16, GlassRLeftBGRight, ImageGray565RGB>(rp);
                  break;
                default :
                  status = 1;
              }
            }
                break;
          case false :
            {
              switch (sf)
              {
                case ifRGB :
                  RenderStereoPair<ImageRGB, DepthUnsigned24, GlassRLeftBGRight, ImageRGB>(rp);
                  break;
                case ifBGR :
                  RenderStereoPair<ImageBGR, DepthUnsigned24, GlassRLeftBGRight, ImageBGR>(rp);
                  break;
                case ifARGB :
                  RenderStereoPair<ImageARGB, DepthUnsigned32, GlassRLeftBGRight, ImageARGB>(rp);
                  break;
                case ifBGRA :
                  RenderStereoPair<ImageBGRA, DepthUnsigned32, GlassRLeftBGRight, ImageBGRA>(rp);
                  break;
                case if555RGB :
                  RenderStereoPair<Image555RGB, DepthUnsigned16, GlassRLeftBGRight, Image555RGB>(rp);
                  break;
                case if565RGB :
                  RenderStereoPair<Image565RGB, DepthUnsigned16, GlassRLeftBGRight, Image565RGB>(rp);
                  break;
                default :
                  status = 1;
              }
            }
        }
      }
      break;
    case gtBGLeftRRight :
      {
        switch (outputGrey)
        {
          case true :
            {
              switch (sf)
              {
                case ifRGB :
                  RenderStereoPair<ImageGrayRGB, DepthUnsigned24, GlassBGLeftRRight, ImageGrayRGB>(rp);
                  break;
                case ifBGR :
                  RenderStereoPair<ImageGrayBGR, DepthUnsigned24, GlassBGLeftRRight, ImageGrayBGR>(rp);
                  break;
                case ifARGB :
                  RenderStereoPair<ImageGrayARGB, DepthUnsigned32, GlassBGLeftRRight, ImageGrayARGB>(rp);
                  break;
                case ifBGRA :
                  RenderStereoPair<ImageGrayBGRA, DepthUnsigned32, GlassBGLeftRRight, ImageGrayBGRA>(rp);
                  break;
                case if555RGB :
                  RenderStereoPair<ImageGray555RGB, DepthUnsigned16, GlassBGLeftRRight, ImageGray555RGB>(rp);
                  break;
                case if565RGB :
                  RenderStereoPair<ImageGray565RGB, DepthUnsigned16, GlassBGLeftRRight, ImageGray565RGB>(rp);
                  break;
                default :
                  status = 1;
              }
            }
                break;

          case false :
            {
              switch (sf)
              {
                case ifRGB :
                  RenderStereoPair<ImageRGB, DepthUnsigned24, GlassBGLeftRRight, ImageRGB>(rp);
                  break;
                case ifBGR :
                  RenderStereoPair<ImageBGR, DepthUnsigned24, GlassBGLeftRRight, ImageBGR>(rp);
                  break;
                case ifARGB :
                  RenderStereoPair<ImageARGB, DepthUnsigned32, GlassBGLeftRRight, ImageARGB>(rp);
                  break;
                case ifBGRA :
                  RenderStereoPair<ImageBGRA, DepthUnsigned32, GlassBGLeftRRight, ImageBGRA>(rp);
                  break;
                case if555RGB :
                  RenderStereoPair<Image555RGB, DepthUnsigned16, GlassBGLeftRRight, Image555RGB>(rp);
                  break;
                case if565RGB :
                  RenderStereoPair<Image565RGB, DepthUnsigned16, GlassBGLeftRRight, Image565RGB>(rp);
                  break;
                default :
                  status = 1;
              }
            }
        }
      }
      break;
```

Comment: Note I have only small portions of the source, nothing proprietary, because I was really tickled with how well this nested despatch technique worked so kept it for future reference. I'm also not claiming to be smart enough to work out exactly how the math for the 3D stereo viewing algorithms worked - that came from the research department based on original hardware inline converters.